# How to call utilities page from settings on HoloLens by code?

Tags: uwp, settings, hololens

I'm  accessing the about page in the windows settings on Hololens by using :

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"ms-settings:about");
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Now, how can I access the utilities page ?

Are there any parameters like ms-settings:*** ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any parameters like ms-settings:*** ?

There are a lot of parameters that could be used to launch utilities page. Such as `ms-settings:workplace`, `ms-settings:emailandaccounts`. For more you could refer [**Launch the Windows Settings app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

And there is no relative description about utilities in the document. If you need this new feature please feel free to ask for this feature on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: Hey Niko thank you for your response! 
But Actually i am trying to access the Utilities page under the system settings from which you can launch the calibration app, as you can see in this link : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/calibration

Comment: Yes I tried it but unfortunately it launches the system settings. I'm not sure but I think that any unknown command starting with ms-settings: launches the default settings page.

Comment: Yes, you are right, If `ms-settings:utilities` is unknown command. it will launch the default settings page.

Comment: And there is no relative description about utilities in the document. If you need this new feature please feel free to ask for this feature on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea! I just made a post on UserVoice.